# What is the actual Market Premium (U.S.) in the book "YOUR COMPLETE GUIDE TO FACTOR-BASED INVESTING" by Berkin and Swedroe

Tags: united-states, stock-markets, beta

In chapter 1 - Market Beta, the authors state that the market beta premium in the US (annually) from 1927-2015 was 8.3% while they also state that the Equity Risk Premium in the US from 1900-2015 was 4.4%.

The authors then go on to use the 8.3% premium through-out the rest of the book.

I don't believe that the premium was 8.3% in 1927-2015 but only 4.4% from 1900-2015. Which number is more accurate?

If I'm asking this question in the wrong place then I am sorry.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Hard to answer the question without additional context or knowing how they arrived at those numbers but I'd guess market beta premium includes a risk free rate whereas equity risk premium doesn't.